# Find physically closest element in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to find the *physically* closest element to a given element in a python dictionary. Let's say, this is my dict:
`dict = {(1,10): "A", (11,23): "A", (24,2): "B", (25,5): "C"}` with such tuples as keys.

I want to find the closest key with value "A" to the last element of that list, `(25,5): "C"`. That would be `(11,23): "A"`. The search should work both to the left and to the right.
Is there any way of doing this? Would a different data structure be better here?

Comment: I think the data structure is inappropriate but I'm not sure I understand your spec very clearly. Why not flip the keys and values and sort it, then do a bisection? Could you offer more details about your use case? Thanks.

Comment: By "close" do you mean euclidean distance, i.e. dist((25,5), (11,23)) = sqrt(14^2 + 18^2) ?

Comment: Since dictionaries and their elements aren't physical, what do you mean by physically closest?

Comment: Or by physically close, do you mean that `(11, 23): "A"` is written down (in the definition of `dict`) closer to `(25, 5): "C"` than `(1, 10): "A"`?

Comment: I am not trying to find the alphabetically closest value, this was just an example. What I am trying to do: for this given element, find the element with specific value X that is physically closest to it in this dictionary. By "physically" I mean exactly what @vahlala is saying.

Comment: So you mean `(11,23): 'A'` is closest in its ordering within the dict??  That is a bit strange: `dict`s are not generally treated as ordered lists (although in Python 3.6+ they're insertion-ordered...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach in base Python:

```py
d = {(1,10): "A", (11,23): "A", (24,2): "B", (25,5): "C"}

# the "target" you're trying to get close to
y = (25,5)

# the keys of the dict sorted by their closeness to y
d2 = sorted(d.keys(),
            key=lambda x: (x[0]-y[0])**2 + (x[1]-y[1])**2)
d2
# [(25, 5), (24, 2), (11, 23), (1, 10)]

# the first (closest) of these points with the label 'A' in the dict
[p for p in d2 if d[p]=='A'][0]
# (11, 23)
```

If you mean "close" in terms of their order within the dict, you could instead do

```py
[p for p in d if d[p]=='A'][-1]
# (11,23)
```

but note in Python <3.6 this will not give meaningful results because `dict`s did not preserve order.  Even in 3.6+ they don't tend to be treated as ordered lists, consider using a `list` instead, for example:

```py
d = [[(1,10), "A"], [(11,23), "A"], [(24,2), "B"], [(25,5), "C"]]
[p[0] for p in d if p[1]=='A'][-1]
# (11,23)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
foo=sorted(dict.keys(), key=lambda x: np.linalg.norm(np.array(x)-np.array((25, 5))))
[x for x in foo if dict[x]=="A"][0]
```

Comment: Could you explain a little, what exactly this is doing? I'm having trouble understanding what's happening here.

Comment: @edrftg21 I assume that by "physical distance" you mean "euclidean distance", the first line sorts the keys by distance from your favorite key, the second extracts the key whose value is "A" and which is closest to your favorite key (so `[0]` gives the first element, which means one with the lowest value).

Answer (score -1):

If you are simply looking for a single point that gives the shortest distance, than you can use `min`:

```
import math
t, t1 = (25,5), 'A'
d = {(1,10): "A", (11,23): "A", (24,2): "B", (25,5): "C"}
r = min(filter(lambda x:d[x] == t1, d), key=lambda x:math.dist(t, x))
```

Output:

```
(11, 23)
```